# Is there a way to declare the same activity multiple times in the manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I need it because each instance has some differences in the declaration arguments, for example: launchMode.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Derive your Activity that give you an separate name for the manifest

```
class ActA extends MyActivity {}
class ActB extends MyActivity {}
class ActC extends MyActivity {}
```

Comment: This is an ugly solution. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Great but same activity cant be declared multiple times in manifeast file.
By declaring we don't any error at compile time.

But would not launch the required activity at runtime and might get runtime exception due conflicts in activity names.